# Using NOT EXISTS while creating a table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
create table wholetable as 
(
    select t1.column1 , t1.column2 from t1
    minus
    select t2.column1, t2.column2 from t2
)
```

Can I modify this query to use `NOT EXISTS` instead of `MINUS`?

Comment: what?, can you elaborate?

Comment: Your query makes no sense.  You have no `WHERE` clause anywhere.  You're basically saying you want to select everything from `TABLE` except for those that are in `TABLE`.  Are these meant to be two separate tables?  But more importantly, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Given that `MINUS` is not supported in all SQL databases, would you let us know which RDMS you are using?

Comment: Yes these are two separate tables,using oracle 11g

Comment: Also, i need only the colum1 and colum2 values from table t1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
create table wholetable as
select t1.column1, t1.column2
  from t1
 where not exists (select *
                     from t2
                    where t2.column1 = t1.column1
                      and t2.column2 = t1.column2)
```